# how do i get a list of string from a list of list that already has a nested list comprehension

Tags: python, loops, nested-lists

I have seen some similar questions but all the solutions I've seen involve creating a nested loop or list comprehension which i already have.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import re

source = Path(r"C:\Test Folder")
target = source / "##Currently Airing"

# This function uses a nested list comprehension to return a list of the
# names in brackets of the folders in the target folder. Returns a list of a list
def target_folder_names():
    return [[name for name in re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', file)] for file in os.listdir(target)]
```

how do get the function to return list of strings instead?

I wrote a loop that prints what I want but I don't know how to change it into a function

```
for file in os.listdir(target):
    for name in re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', file):
        print(name)
```

Comment: Seems like you have the nesting backward in the comprehension. Have you tried: `[name for file in os.listdir(target) for name in re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', file)]`

Comment: @Mark Thanks a lot, I just tried your suggestion and it worked. Could you pls tell me how you knew the nesting was backwards?

Comment: It's a little counterintuitive until you get used it, but nesting in list comprehensions follows the same order as nested for loops. Notice that the loop that worked for you starts with `os.listdir` then `findall()`.